# How to get error line number when validation xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-validation

I have an xml like this:

```
<A>
   <b>some content</b>
   <c>some content</c>
   <d>
       <d1>some content</d1>
       <d2>some content</d2>
   </d>
</A>
```

I want to validate some xml file, which must conform to the xml format above, that is to say:
only element "b", "c", "d" can be child of element "A", and only element "d1" and "d2" can be child of element "d", and content of "b" can only be characters. If some xml file failed to conform to these rules, the program report all the error lines numbers, not just the first error line number. And JDK is 5. How to validate this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a XML schema to define the rules and then use Validator in javax.xml.validation to validate it.Have a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html).

Comment: And as for the line numbers, the schema validator should report them to the application.